# Disabling editing option on TDBGrid doesn't function

Tags: c++builder, dbgrid, c++builder-6

When creating TDBGrid components dynamically at runtime, i can't forbid user to edit values in cells. This is how I am trying to accomplish this type of behaviour:

```c
TDBGrid *DbGrid = new TDBGrid(Owner);
DbGrid->Options = DbGrid->Options >> dgEditing;
```

When disabling **dgEditing** in form designer all is functioning correctly. I can't find the difference between these two cases. What should I do to disable edit of DBGrid cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to do this in following way:

DbGrid->Options = TDBGridOptions(DbGrid->Options) >> dgEditing

but I do not know what is the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the Seattle version of C++Builder in that I am unable to programmatically change whether the DbGrid allows or disallows editing. The DbGrid->Options values CAN be changed without requiring the TDBGridOptions() cast but the DbGrid does not follow what the DbGrid->Options are set to. If they are set in the object inspector for dgEditing enabled, then the DbGrid always allows editing no matter what the state of DbGrid->Options.dgEditing is and if in the object inspector dgEditing is disabled then the DbGrid never allows editing. It at first APPEARS to work (i.e. the highliting of rows vs cells changes). I have tested this using both DbGrid->Options.ToInt() and DbGrid->Options.Contains(dgEditing) to ensure I'm not stumbling over myself.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to make it work.

If you set the `dgEditing` to true (for the Options of the `DBGrid` in the Object Inspector), this will let the user edit at any time. Then, set `DBGrid->ReadOnly=false` when the user should not be allowed to edit.

I did not have any luck trying to set the individual `DBGrid->Columns->Items[ii]->ReadOnly=false`. The program did not prevent me from doing that, but it did ignore whatever I had in it.

I wrote a special small test program with minimum components and was able to get good results just by setting the `dgEditing` to true in the object inspector and then changed `dgEditing` to false when I wanted to prevent the user from editing, but when I put it into my full program, something prevented the `DBGrid` from working.

The `DBGrid->ReadOnly` may be a work-around for someone else also.